# Django Query with Left and Inner Joins

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I have 3 django models which are connected like this:

```
class AppUser(models.Model):
     pass

class UserDevice(models.Model):
     user = ForeignKey(AppUser, related_name='user_devices')

class Token(models.Model):
     user_device = OneToOneField(UserDevice, related_name='auth_token')
```

I have a situation in which I need to perform a query which **Left Joins** AppUser with UserDevice and **Inner Joins** UserDevice with Token (because I only need UserDevices which have a Token in system).
But whatever I've written until now using django's *prefetch_related* and *Prefetch objects*, hasn't been useful. The problem is that the ORM uses either Left Outer join for both joins or Inner join for both of them.
Is it possible to achieve what I want using ORM or should I necessarily write raw SQL for this?

Comment: I am a bit confuse, the query you are looking for is `AppUser LEFT JOIN UserDevice INNER JOIN Token`?

Comment: @cabesuon yes exactly.